# subprocess.Popen locks -- what to do to ensure no locks?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have the following working Python code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("[cscript, DoSomething.vbs]", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print("finish")
```

`doSomething.vbs`is a vbscript that completes after 2 to 3 hours.Oddly enough, Python locks and needs a keyboard interrupt `ctrl-c` in order for the script to reach the last line `print("finish")` .

What do i need to do to ensure that the script will not lock?
Do note that I do not need to pass any variables to the `doSomething.vbs`.

Comment: Maybe don't wait for it to `communicate`?

Comment: Is - [subprocess popen stdout locking up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10149149/2823755) - similar to your issue?

Comment: [Interacting with a long-running child process in Python](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/)